# Custom loss function error: tensor does not have a grad_fn

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

Trying to utilize a custom loss function and getting error ‘RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn’. Error occurs during loss.backward()

I’m aware that all computations must be done in tensors with ‘require_grad = True’. I’m having trouble implementing that as my code requires a nested for loop. I believe it could be the for loop. Is there a way to create an empty tensor and append it? Below is my code.

```
def Gaussian_Kernal(x, mu, sigma):
  p = (1./(math.sqrt(2. * math.pi * (sigma**2)))) * torch.exp((-1.) * (((Variable(x)**2) - mu)/(2. * (sigma**2))))
  return p

class MEE(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MEE,self).__init__()

  def forward(self,output, target, mu, variance):

    error = torch.subtract(Variable(output),Variable(target))
  
    error_diff = []
    for i in range(0, error.size(0)):
      for j in range(0, error.size(0)):
        error_diff.append(error[i] - error[j])

    error_diff = torch.cat(error_diff)
    torch.tensor(error_diff,requires_grad=True)

    loss = (1./(target.size(0)**2)) * torch.sum(Gaussian_Kernal(Variable(error_diff), mu, variance*(2**0.5)))

    loss = Variable(loss)

    return loss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you operate on Tensors and apply PyTorch functions and basic operators, it should work. Therefore no need to wrap your variables with `torch.tensor` or `Variable`. The latter has been being deprecated (since v0.4, I believe).

> The Variable API has been deprecated: Variables are no longer
> necessary to use autograd with tensors. Autograd automatically
> supports Tensors with requires_grad set to True. [PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html?highlight=variable#variable-deprecated)

I'm assuming `output` and `target` are tensors and `mu` and `variance` are reals and not tensors? Then, the first dimension of `output` and `target` would be the batch.

```
def Gaussian_Kernel(x, mu, sigma):
  p = (1./(math.sqrt(2. * math.pi * (sigma**2)))) * torch.exp((-1.) * (((x**2) - mu)/(2. * (sigma**2))))
  return p

class MEE(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MEE, self).__init__()

  def forward(self, output, target, mu, variance):
    error = output - target

    error_diff = []
    for i in range(0, error.size(0)):
      for j in range(0, error.size(0)):
        error_diff.append(error[i] - error[j]) # Assuming that's the desired operation

    error_diff = torch.cat(error_diff)
    kernel = Gaussian_Kernel(error_diff, mu, variance*(2**0.5))
    loss = (1./(target.size(0)**2))*torch.sum(kernel)
    
    return loss
```

Comment: your assumptions are correct. mu and variance are reals. First dimension of tensors is batch size. I think the issue is the error_diff list. I'm computing the difference in errors for each point of the batch. I think the copy from a list to a tensor results in the error but I'm not sure. Is there a way to do this operation with just tensors? I don't think its an error with my network because simple MSELoss() works well.

Comment: It should be `error[i] - error[j]` then. I don't think creating a new list `error_diff` is an issue as long as you create a stack or concatenate them into a tensor afterwards. Is it still not working?

Comment: It's still throwing the same error. I maintained the error[i] - error[j]. torch.cat creates a copy of the list into a tensor.

Comment: I can share it over colab as well if that helps

Comment: its under 'MEE no noise'.

Comment: I had a look at your notebook. Since I don't have your data, could you give me the shapes of `data` and `targets`? Also can you give the exact error message, with the line concerned.

Comment: data shape is [10,10,1] and target shape [10,1]. batch size being 10. the error message is at line 57 where i call .backward(). so the error value itself computes fine

Comment: It's working for me, make sure to remove `Variable` wrapping up `x` in your `Gaussian_Kernel` function, I think you forgot to remove it.

Comment: you're correct, thank you. Its computing the gradients xD